# Backburner, Back Burner or Back-Burner?

Tags: orthography

When in the context of

> Putting something on the *.

which is correct? Backburner, Back Burner or Back-Burner?
Are there international differences here, or are some of them really just wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you can use any of those three.

[Cambridge Dictionary uses 'on the back burner'](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/on-the-back-burner)

[Whereas Google define lists the other two options](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define%3A+backburner&oq=define)

On the second link you can also see some of the variations other online dictionaries use.

So, I'd say it's probably just a matter of preference.